# How to display the console content in web browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have example1.js nodejs file which is running fine in console

How can we do it to show in web browser using http request?

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('news.ycombinator.com', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('span.comhead').each(function(i, element){
      var a = $(this).prev();
      console.log(a.text());
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: var request = require('request');

var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://news.ycombinator.com', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('span.comhead').each(function(i, element){
      var a = $(this).prev();
      console.log(a.text());
    });
  }
});

Answer (score 1):

> How can we do it to show in web browser using http request?

You can't.

The request module is for **making** requests. You can't use it to listen for them.

---

You could do it with [built-in http module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html). You could find an example of using it on [the Node.js homepage](http://nodejs.org/).

But it's best to pick one of [the HTTP server libraries](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=http%20server) available in npm.

Or to use one of node.js web application frameworks:

- [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/)
- [express](http://expressjs.com/)
- [koa](http://koajs.com/)

Then replace all your `console.log` statements with calls that put the text in the HTTP response bodies (as per the documentation for whichever module you pick).

Comment: how can i access that local variable 'a' in outside      var a = $(this).prev();